# If $\omega$ is compactly supported form then so is $d\omega$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

If $\omega$ is a compactly supported differential form then so is $d\omega$. Is it true?

Comment: Hint: out of support you are taking the differential of zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In local coordinates, if (using Einstein notation) $\omega=f_I\cdot dx^I$ (where $I$ are monotone sequences of appropriate length) we have:
$$d\omega= \frac{\partial f_I}{\partial x_i} dx^i\wedge dx^I$$
In particular, support of $\omega$ is the union of supports of $f_I$, and that contains the union of supports of their partial derivatives, which contains the support of $d\omega$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think it would be so easy!!!

Comment: @user135988: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in coordinate-free way as follows. Let $p \in M \smallsetminus \text{supp }\omega$ be arbitrary. Since $M \smallsetminus \text{supp }\omega$ is open, we have a neighbourhood $U \subseteq M \smallsetminus \text{supp }\omega$ contain $p$. This means  $\omega \equiv 0$ on $U$ and so $d\omega \equiv 0$ on $U$. This equivalent to
    $$
 \{p \in M : (d\omega)_p \neq 0 \} \subseteq  \text{ supp }\omega.
 $$
    This means supp $d\omega \subseteq $ supp $\omega$. Since supp $\omega$ is compact, so is supp $d\omega$.